# Can't download ebooks after downloading xampp

Tags: download, xampp

For some reason I can't download ebooks anymore ever since I downloaded xampp. I guess there is something wrong with the directory.

This error continues to occur: 
"Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /i/etNY9wf on this server."

Not sure why this issue is occurring. Need help resolving the issue so I can download again.

Answer (score 0):

since you don't describe in your question how you are downloading the ebooks, I am guessing that you are using a P2P program or any other program for downloading. Some Software use port `80` and `XAMPP` is using port `80` too. It might be a port conflict.

Some troubleshooting:

### Option 1

Stop `XAMPP` Apache Service (From `XAMPP Control Panel`) and try to download some eBook.

### Option 2

Uninstall `XAMPP` and try to download some eBook

I am pretty sure that the issue is with the port conflict. Can you please provide more information about how you download those eBooks?